# Is there any way to transfer my chrome data to new pc?

Tags: google-chrome, backup, clone, google-chrome-app, restore

I have a ton on settings and accounts in chrome in my old PC. Now, I really need to move the data to new PC.
Is there any way to do it ? I really afraid of losing data. :((

Please give me an suggestion to transfer my chrome data to new PC :D.

Answer (score 0):

If you are logged into chrome with a google account, All of your chrome data should sync automatically. If not, there are options to export bookmarks and saved passwords from chrome settings. Hope this helps!